# Yii 2: using Event can not pass data from trigger() to on()

Tags: yii2

I try to add a event after search onthe `var_dump` is excuted, but data did
not pass through. Why ?

trigger:

```
class ContentSearch extends Content
{
    const EVENT_AFTER_SEARCH = 'afterSearch';

    public function search($params)
    {
        $e = new ModelEvent;
        $e->data = $this;
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_SEARCH, $e);
    }
}
```

on:

```
class ContentController extends Controller 
{
   public function actionIndex()
   {
        $searchModel = new ContentSearch();

        $searchModel->on($searchModel::EVENT_AFTER_SEARCH, function ($event) {
            var_dump($event->data);
            die;
        });

        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
   }
}
```

dump

```
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are wrong about event `data` usage :

Read this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-event.html#$data-detail

> The data that is passed to `yii\base\Component::on()` when attaching an event handler.

And this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-component.html#on()-detail

About the third param :

> The data to be passed to the event handler when the event is triggered

Anyway, you don't need this, you could simply use `$event->sender` :

```
function ($event) {
    var_dump($event->sender); // this will dump your ContentSearch model
    die;
}
```